# How can we can we calculate the factorial of a number using python lambda function without recursion

Tags: python

I wanted to calculate the the factorial of a number using python lambda function without recursion.

I did without lamda function

```
def factorial_number(num):
fact = 1
while(num>=1):
    fact = num* fact;
    num = num-1
return  fact


factorial_number(5)
```

I have tried the below code without recursion(using lambda).

```
factorial_number  = lambda num : 1 while(num>=1) fact = fact*num num = num-1 return fact
```

The above code doesn't work.

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-62f7b66fbfd2>", line 1
factorial_number  = lambda num : 1 while(num>=1) fact = fact*num num = num-1 return fact
                                   ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

But i want to implement using lamda function, without in-built functions and  without recursive method. so that i can learn more how to use lamba funcitons effectively.

please help me with the code.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: ```lambda num : 1 if num <= 1 else num*x(num-1)```? You call it using ```x(3)``` or whatever number

Comment: try adding what all you have tried so far. else your question might be down voted and can impact you negatively. (i don't prefer to down vote)

Comment: I think [this](https://www.codesansar.com/python-programming-examples/one-line-code-find-factorial.htm) will help

Comment: Is this an assignment ?

Answer (score 1):

```
def factorial(n):
    t = 1
    for i in range(n, 1, -1):
        t *= i
    return t

>>> factorial(4)
24
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `functools.reduce()`

```
from functools import reduce
num = int(input('Enter number: '))
fact = lambda num: reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, range(1, num+1))

print(f'{num}! = {fact(num)}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use math.factorial.

```
import math
fctrl = lambda: math.factorial(x)
```

or

```
from math import factorial
fctrl = lambda: factorial(x)
```

Comment: Neither of those snippets will run without raising a `NameError`

Comment: Yep.```x``` is not defined

Comment: Also, using ```lambda```is useless here

Comment: I dont want in-built  functions to be used